# Discard Webservice call if no response in specified time

Tags: java, web-services

How do i stop invoked webservice from client program(Java) if there is no response from server within specific time. If there is no response from server within specified time, I need to prepare error message and send the message to UI.

```
try {
    applicationProcessRs = service.processApplication(applicationProcessRq);
} catch ( ApplicationProcessFaultMsg e ) {
    log.error( e.getMessage(), e );
}
```

Thanks,
Ramakrishna K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to set timeouts for specific services, once you've created your proxy you need to cast it to a BindingProvider (which you know already), get the request context and set your properties. The online JAX-WS documentation is wrong, these are the correct property names

```java
MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterfaceService().getMyInterfaceSOAP();
Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider)myInterface).getRequestContext();
requestContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 3000); // Timeout in millis
requestContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 1000); // Timeout in millis
myInterface.callMyRemoteMethodWith(myParameter);
```

Of course, this is a horrible way to do things, I would create a nice factory for producing these binding providers that can be injected with the timeouts you want.

Note that the `REQUEST_TIMEOUT` / `CONNECT_TIMEOUT` properties are actually inherited from the Sun-internal class `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties` and (at least on 32-bit Linux) javac 1.6.0_27 and javac 1.7.0_03 fail to compile this code (similar to [JDK-6544224 : (reflect) sun.reflect.misc is missing from ct.sym](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6544224)). You need to pass `-XDignore.symbol.file` to javac to make it work.